# Correctly write a one-liner mathematical expression in Python

Tags: python

I have a problem that asks me to write **one line** of python code to do the following:

```
Calculate the total cost of an item whose original price is $10. You have a 30% discount on it and have to pay 5% state tax. The shipping would cost $7.5.
```

Following is what I came up with:

```
10 - (10 * 30 / 100) + (10 - (10 * 30 / 100)) * 5 / 100 + 7.5
```

As you can see, I am calculating 10 less 30% twice in the above code. I could use a variable to hold `10 - (10 * 30 / 100)` but as the problem statement says, I need to do it in **one line**. Is there a better (read **pythonic**) way to achieve this?

This problem is from Sam's teach yourself Python in 24 hours book, btw (sorry!).

Comment: This is more of a math question than a Python question. Factorize your expression! Plus you can't learn any language thorougly in 24 hours...

Comment: print((10*.7)*1.05 + 7.5)

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I could certainly use factorization but that is not the point here. I could even pre-calculate the percentage values (like many have suggested below). But I want to do this using code and don't want to use mathematics skills (I want to learn python not maths). So this does not seem to be a mathematics problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use basic math operations:

```
print ((0.7*100)*1.05)+7.5
#81.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables in a one liner, but you can simplify your solution like this.

```
print 10 * 0.7 * 1.05 + 7.5
```

EDIT: 
As I mentioned in my comment, The code I posted is all you need. Doing anything more complicated than that can't really be useful as more than an intellectual exercise.

For example ...

```
print map(lambda x: x + 7.5, map(lambda x: x*1.05, map(lambda x: x*.7, [10])))[0]
```

Comment: Could you please show me how I can do that? Sorry, total n00b here.

Comment: The code I posted is all you need. Doing anything more complicated than that can't really be useful as more than an intellectual exercise.

Comment: I know but am just curious at how can I define and use a variable in one line.

Answer (score 0):

`int/int` can lose precision. You need to `divide by 100.0` or `float(100)` instead of just `100` to get the right result. or insert this code `from __future__ import division`.

```
In [17]: 10 - (10 * 30 / 100) + (10 - (10 * 30 / 100)) * 5 / 100 + 7.5
Out[17]: 14.5
In [19]: from __future__ import division
In [20]: 10 - (10 * 30 / 100) + (10 - (10 * 30 / 100)) * 5 / 100 + 7.5
Out[20]: 14.85
```

Comment: Or use Python 3 where int->float conversion is the default behavior.